# Sample size inflation in longitudinal studies

Tags: time-series, panel-data, sample-size, effect-size, statistical-power

I know that in longitudinal studies with multiple time point assessments, the fixed effect sample size is inflated and therefore the statistical power is increased.  I read before, that the inflation happens by a factor of (1+(n-1)p), where n is the number of assessments after baseline and p is correlation between assessments. However, I can not find a reference for this. My questions: 1- Is the formula above correct? and 2-are you aware about any reference to support this? I am not a statistician so I would appreciate using simple language.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "sample size"? The sample size should be determined entirely by how many non-missing observations you have at each timepoint.

Comment: Hi Kodiologist, perhaps using 'statistical power' inflation in the title might be a better option. Thanks for your comment